# Cython: a class needs to have as its attribute a python list of Cython extension types -- thus, this class cannot be an extension type itself?

Tags: python, design-patterns, cython

Let us say I have a Cython extension type named `Point`.

Then, I need to create a class called `Points`, which has as one of its attributes, a Python list of `Point` objects. Now, Python lists, as far as I understand, cannot be attributes of an extension type, as only C data types can be.

I want to use Python lists to hold the list of Cython extension types, because I have heard that its the easiest way to do so, and access of Python lists through Cython is quit efficient.

Thus, `Points` has to be a normal Python/Cython class, not an extension type, correct? That way, I can do the following:

```
def class Points:
    def __init__(self, num_points):
        self.points = [Point() for x in range(num_points)]
```

Do I understand correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is no such limitation, Cython extension types can have arbitrary Python objects as attributes. For example you could declare your `Points` class in the following way:

```
cdef class Points:
    cdef list points
    def __init__(self, num_points):
        self.points = [Point() for x in range(num_points)]
```

Note that you need to declare all attributes of Cython extension types in advance. If you do not want to restrict the attribute to a specific Python object you can also use `object` instead of `list`. If you want to expose your points attribute to Python, i.e. allow direct access from Python, you need to declare it as `public` (i.e. `cdef public list points`).

Have a look at the documentation about [attributes of extension types](http://docs.cython.org/src/reference/extension_types.html#attributes) for more details and the second example of the [properties](http://docs.cython.org/src/reference/extension_types.html#properties) section also provides an example how an extension type can wrap a list without providing direct access.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about any such restriction with Cython extension types. But, from the [standard documentation on general extension types](https://docs.python.org/2/extending/newtypes.html), it's clear you can create arbitrary `PyObject`s as member variables in an extension type (see [the Noddy2 example](https://docs.python.org/2/extending/newtypes.html#adding-data-and-methods-to-the-basic-example) with unrestricted `PyObject` members `first` and `last` which are later refined to be restricted to string types). If you went this route, you could expose a member as a `PyObject` and pass it a `list` by convention or fully restrict it to be a `list`.

Comment: Cython extension types might not be the same thing as Python extension types?